# python ultrajson dependencies? unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python

I am trying to install ultrajson (ujson) on windows for python 2.7

I got the file here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson/1.33 (.zip) and executed:

```
 python setup.py install
```

It starts installing fine, then runs into the error:

```
unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

That error message occurs when Python can't find a suitable C compiler on your PC. Do you have Visual Studio 2008 installed?

Comment: Actually, do you have other recommendations for compilers?

Comment: @user984003: No, VS is perfectly fine.

Comment: I can't find a link to download it anywhere!

Comment: Hm, it might not be available on MS's own homepage. But googling "visual studio 2008 express download full" should give you enough other links.